# realm crash on startup suddenly : "Unable to open a realm at path " "Realm file initial open failed: Invalid mnemonic"

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js

**Crash, Error: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/user/0/xxx/files/geo.realm': Realm file initial open failed: Invalid mnemonic.**

In our React Native project, this error has started to appear for 10-15% of our users since our last release, yet we changed nothing to do with Realm in that release.  Those users who get it, seem to get it repeatedly (locked out).  The pattern seems to be that a new install works fine, then when the app is launched subsequently, they get crashes on startup over and over.  Some users have reported that this then has magically resolved itself.  It only appears to be Android users.  Mystifying.

Our Realm version 10.8.0 and has been for a long time.

Our encrypt key is static hardcoded.

Any insights appreciated.

cheers